# How can I put tabs in a table view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

When a user clicks on a cell in table , the view should switch to a tabbed view.

The content on each of the tabs will be different depending on which cell the user selects.

How can I make something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need navigation based application. Read the [tutorial](http://www.matthewcasey.co.uk/2010/05/23/tutorial-introducing-uinavigationcontroller-part-1/)

Shortly: create UINavigationController, add your table controller as a root controller of the navigation controller. Then in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` just push your tab controller into the navigation controller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabViewController animated:YES];
}
```